# How to approach a function call sequence prediction using Deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have a input alphanumeric string of max length 10 and i have set of four different functions like alllower(), allupper(), containsvowel(), containsnumber(). Lets call those functions as f1, f2, f3, f4. Depends on the string each function would return 1 if the condition is satisfied and if the condition is false then the function would return 0.

Example:

```
Input : baby
Then : f1 -> 1, f2 -> 0, f3 -> 1, f4 -> 0
So the ranking would be : f1 f3 f2 f4
```

Now i need to approach this problem using deep learning

I have generated the ranking using a python code on my own for around 1000 strings and corresponding ranking

```
string f1 f2 f3 f4 
baby    1  3  2  4
Hello   2  3  1  4
.
.
.
```

Now if i give a new string my deep learning algorithm should predict the ranking of the functions accordingly

Also suggest some efficient way to convert those strings into corresponding integers to feed as input in the input layer.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to use DL for something that can be trivially implemented with simple code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't really see why you need to apply deep learning to this problem. **Deep** learning assumes a deep neural network which is useless in your case. Anyway, in order to apply NN, you need to encode input and output of your problem. As to the input, you may transform each word into a list of its letters' positions in the string 01...9abc...zABC...Z (it's not optimal but it encodes enough information) and then transform it to their 0-1 characteristic vectors or apply Embedding as the first layer. As to the output, basically you need to predict one of 24 (4*3*2) orderings of numbers (1,2,3,4), so you may encode them as 24-dimensional vectors and you should apply `softmax` activation in the last layer of your NN.